# Transformation algorithms for numerical values similar to functionality of Soundex, Metaphone, etc

Tags: java, algorithm, language-agnostic, numbers, pattern-matching

I'm working on implementing probablistic matching for person record searching. As part of this, I plan to have blocking performed before any scoring is done. Currently, there are a lot of good options for transforming strings so that they can be stored and then searched for, with similar strings matching each other (things like soundex, metaphone, etc).

However, I've struggled to find something similar for purely numeric values. For example, it would be nice to be able to block on a social security number and not have numbers that are off or have transposed digits be removed from the results. 123456789 should have blocking results for 123456780 or 213456789.

Now, there are certainly ways to simply compare two numerical values to determine how similar they are, but what could I do when there are million of numbers in the database? It's obviously impractical to compare them all (and that would certainly invalidate the point of blocking).

What would be nice would be something where those three SSNs above could somehow be transformed into some other value that would be stored. Purely for example, imagine those three numbers ended up as AAABBCCC after this magical transformation. However, something like 987654321 would be ZZZYYYYXX and 123547698 would be AAABCCBC or something like that.

So, my question is, is there a good transformation for numeric values like there exists for alphabetical values? Or, is there some other approach that might make sense (besides some highly complex or low performing SQL or logic)?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by blocking?  Is a blocking function something that takes a record and returns a list of candidate keys?  Are these candidate keys then used to restrict pairwise compares to pairs of records that matched at least one blocking candidate key?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct. So, if you have a record with SSN 1234 you want to find matches for, you'd like to exclude fairly obvious non matches like 5555. Or, if a gender is male, then you can exclude females from result to be scored. Then, you should have a small box of records to score or to apply further blocking rounds using other attributes (like last name). It's impractical to score the current record against every existing record so that's why blocking is done. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to realize is that social security numbers are basically strings of digits.  You really want to treat them like you would strings rather than numbers.

The second thing to realize is that your blocking function maps from a record to a list of strings that identify comparison worthy sets of items.

Here is some Python code to get you started.  (I know you asked for Java, but I think the Python is clear and you aren't paying me enough to write it in Java :P ).  The basic idea is to take your input record, simulate roughing it up in multiple ways (to get your blocking keys), and then group on by any match on those blocking keys.

```
import itertools

def transpositions(s):
  for pos in range(len(s) - 1):
    yield s[:pos] + s[pos + 1] + s[pos] + s[pos + 2:]

def substitutions(s):
  for pos in range(len(s)):
    yield s[:pos] + '*' + s[pos+1:]

def all_blocks(s):
  return itertools.chain([s], transpositions(s), substitutions(s))

def are_blocked_candidates(s1, s2):
  return bool(set(all_blocks(s1)) & set(all_blocks(s2)))

assert not are_blocked_candidates('1234', '5555')
assert are_blocked_candidates('1234', '1239')
assert are_blocked_candidates('1234', '2134')
assert not are_blocked_candidates('1234', '1255')
```

Comment: This seems similar to what I was thinking of doing and it seems there really is no better solution, so this is what I shall do. Thanks.